# When every finitely generated submodule of an R-module is cyclic?

Tags: ring-theory, homological-algebra, projective-module, flatness

We know that if R is a noetherian ring then every submodule of a finitely generated module is finitely generated. In case R is absolutely flat, we have every finitely generated ideal is principal, can we extend this results to R- modules, i.e have we every finitely generated submodule of an R-module is cyclic?

Answer (score 1):

A module is called a **Bézout module** if its f.g. submodules are all cyclic.  The resource I would recommend with the most contents about this type of module is

> Tuganbaev, Askar A. Semidistributive modules and rings. Vol. 449. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.